# How to set state of an element in div based on the state of other element using css

Tags: html, css, typescript

```
<div class="ms-OverflowSet commandMenu root-236" role="menubar">
    <div class="ms-OverflowSet-item item-237">
        <button type="button" class="ms-Button ms-Button--commandBar commandMenu-item root-239" data-is-focusable="true" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-119">
                <i data-icon-name="Edit" class="ms-Button-icon icon-241" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-OverflowSet-overflowButton overflowButton-238">
        <button type="button" class="ms-Button ms-Button--commandBar commandMenu-overflowitem root-239" aria-label="More" data-is-focusable="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-119">
                <i data-icon-name="MoreVertical" class="ms-Button-menuIcon menuIcon-242" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

By default "ms-Button ms-Button--commandBar commandMenu-item root-239" and are hidden "ms-Button ms-Button--commandBar commandMenu-overflowitem root-239"

I want to set state of both of them to visible if .commandMenu-overflowitem aria-expanded value is true "true"

```
.commandMenu-overflowitem[aria-expanded="true"]{
    visibility: visible;
    display: flex
}
```

Above is working to set state of commandMenu-overflowitem

Similarly, I tried to set state of commandMenu-item as below, but it doesn't work

```
.commandMenu-overflowitem[aria-expanded="true"] .commandMenu-item{
    visibility: visible;
    display: flex
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that with css only. You need JS. This question came up on the REACT questions list. Is related to REACT?

If is ReactJs, you will set a value in the state based on the first div and check for this state in the second div. Depending on the value you can show a different class. The way you are describing the problem is a bit confusing. Setting the state of a div..I assume is changing the class of a div based on an another div class..or whatever value you will save in state.